# Fastest way to create a list of overlapping substrings from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, performance, cython

I'm trying to generate a list of all overlapping n-length substrings in a given string.

For example, for an n of `6` and the string `"hereismystring"` I would generate the list `["hereis", "ereism", "reismy", ..., "string"]`. The trivial code I'm using right now looks like this:

```
n = 6
l = len(string)
substrings = [string[i:(i + n)] for i in xrange(l - n + 1)]
```

Easy enough. Problem is, I'd like to speed this up (I have very many very long strings). Is there a faster technique in Python? Will dropping down to Cython help at all given that Python's string routines are in C anyhow?

For reference, this technique takes about 100us on my machine (a new Macbook Pro) for a 500-length string and an n of 30.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Cython will definitely give you more speed, but do you really need that optimization?

Comment: FWIW, on my old macbook, using pypy instead of CPython dropped the time down to ~32 us from ~150 us, at least after it warmed up.  If you only need a factor of a couple, it might be worth trying.

Comment: What do you plan on doing with these substrings once generated?  That could inform the decision.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a step back from the issue of which Python coding technique will be the fastest, I would approach the problem differently. Since all the strings are the same length, and all come from a single source string, why not simply work with the ranges of characters directly, rather than convert them into proper strings? You would avoid a lot of allocation and copying, but you would have to adjust your code to know that each "string" is n characters long.

In other words, just read ranges from the source string directly when you want to work with a substring. You'll be working with the characters you want as fast as they can be pulled from cache. You could express a "substring" as merely an offset into the source string.

Sometimes if you want ultra-fast performance you have to leave familiar data structures behind. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> d = deque("hereismystring")
>>> s = ''.join(d)[:6]
>>> while not len(s) % 6:
...    print s
...    _ = d.popleft()
...    s = ''.join(d)[:6]
... 
hereis
ereism
reismy
eismys
ismyst
smystr
mystri
ystrin
string
>>>
```

I believe deque is O(1) while lists are O(n)

Comment: This is slower than OPs solution. `deque` generation is in-fact `O(nlon n)` operation and moreover, retrieving an element has complexity `O(logn)`, so retrieving all the elements would have a complexity   `O(nlogn)`. Another operation is join which runs for `n` times for each of the `n - 6` slices. Thus the `join` operation has Order of Complexity `O(n^2)`. Summing up, for the entire operation, the Order of complexity is `O(n^2)`. On a Test run, deque implementation is almost 7 times slower.